# Intel Fortran on Visual Studio 2013 64 bit debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2013, 64-bit, visual-studio-debugging, intel-fortran

I'm using **Intel Visual Fortran Composer XE 2013 SP1 Update 3** and debugging in **Visual Studio 2013 Update 2**'s IDE with this simple program:

```
program Console1

implicit none

! Variables
integer(4) testInt
! Body of Console1
print *, 'Hello World'
testInt = 7
end program Console1
```

When the EXE for this program is compiled with the "IA 32" (the Win32 platform) ifort compiler, the debugging works as expected. The watch on `testInt` changes from a random value to 7.

But, when I use the "Intel (R) 64" (the x64 platform) compiler by setting the project to the x64 platform, the debugger will stop at correct break points. But the watch on `testInt` reports "Undefined address" instead of 7.

What's going on here? How can I enable correct debugging for 64 bit Fortran compilations?

Comment: We're working your question in the Intel user forum. VS2013 Update 2 seems to have broken something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has been escalated to Intel development. In the meantime, I suggest uninstalling Update 2 to VS2013, which you can do through Programs and Features > View Installed Updates. Once that is done, x64 debugging of Fortran programs works again. Further discussion can be found at https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/515943

Comment: I have Intel Composer XE 2013 SP1 Update 5 installed, and still see this problem. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/515943#comment-1797611

Comment: There's also a workaround posted in https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/515943#comment-1793913